# How to use the same virtual machine on different hosts without frequently copying the whole VM folder?

Tags: vmware

I have two computers, one in the company and another in my home, respectively. Most of my work is done in the Ubuntu virtual machine, so currently I have to put it in an external hard drive to share between my computers.

I have to carry it with me on and off work and the experience is too bad since the I/O speed of my hard drive is limited, while my two computers in the office and home both have SSDs. So directly accessing a virtual machine from the computer's SSD drive is way faster than accessing from my portable hard drive.

Thus I have attempted to use snapshots as checkpoints to sync between computers to avoid copying the whole VM folder across two hosts and it somehow failed.

Is there any cheap way to sync a virtual machine between two hosts without copying the whole VM folder?

Comment: Can you distinguish between the files you change and the Ubuntu system itself? For example, can you restrict the things you change to your /home directory? If yes, you could leave the Ubuntu system image unchanged, and just mount in the external hardware onto a /home directory. This will still make data access slower than SSD, but it wouldn't be as bad. It's also simpler to e.g. `rsync` just your home directory.

Comment: Snapshots are for temporary use and not for backups of machines. Further, machines tend to get out of sync because of updates and (perhaps) unintended changes. So in line with the above post, create a common file structure that allows you to move a folder or set of files easily. That is what I would do in this circumstance

Answer (score 0):

Use
[Shared Folders](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Workstation-Pro/12.0/com.vmware.ws.using.doc/GUID-D6D9A5FD-7F5F-4C95-AFAB-EDE9335F5562.html)
to put your work files, meaning the ones you are modifying, on the host,
but this way also usable from the guest.

You may use any mechanism to resync these files between the work and home computers.

For example, you may sync the folders to an online repository such as Dropbox
or others, so the latest files are always available.
Or even use the lowly email.

This solution avoids carrying the VM itself back and forth, just your own
files.